# [zetapush]Error in macro: code=SUB_ASSIGN - Message = Assignment failed

Tags: macros

When calling a macro I have the following error in response:

> code=SUB_ASSIGN
>
> Message = Assignment failed
>
> Location= Reduce at line 65 of file mymacro.zms

the line 65 is

```
/** Reduce */
var b = gda(GDA).reduce {
    table: 'myTable',
    start: __parameters.key + '##',
    stop: __parameters.key + '##a',
    page: {
        pageNumber: 0,
        pageSize: 100000000
    },
    initialValue: {
        tR: tR,
        count: 0    
    },
    'columns': ['col1', 'col2'],
    'function': usr:myfunc
};
```

Seen on Android SDK (not on JS SDK) and not 100% reproducible.

What's the meaning of this error and how can I correct it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (poorly documented) meaning of SUB_ASSIGN is that an assignment with a syntax like `a.b.c = d;` has failed.
More precisely, the left hand operand is made of several hierarchical sub-parts (in my example a, b, and c).
Note that SUB_ASSIGN reports a programming error, which you should guard against : 
when assigning a.b.c, at least a.b must exist and be not null.
A code pattern such as this one should do the trick:

```
// the ?? operator returns true when an expression is defined and not null
if (! a.b ??) {
    a.b = {};
}
...
a.b.c = 0;
```

or, shorter, if applicable :

```
if (! a.b ??) {
    a.b = {c:0};
}
```

The relevant documentation for '??' can be found in [the official API reference documentation](https://ref.zpush.io/#macro_cat_operators)

As your code does not include such a statement anyway, I suppose that the actual error does not lie in your reduce call, but inside your callback function (usr:myfunc).

Moreover, to ease further debugging :
the error report you gave does not seem to contain the full stack trace up to the callback of the 'reduce' call. This might very well be a missing/not-yet-implemented feature of the zetapush API (which you could request...).